# Why would a parent class want to use a instance of child class in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

The source code of `process.py` in the multiprocessing package uses the following pattern; pay attention to the relation between `Process`, `_MainProcess` and `_current_process`.

```
class Process(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Process objects represent activity that is run in a separate process                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    The class is analagous to `threading.Thread`                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    '''                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    _Popen = None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}):                                                                                                                                                                                            
        assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        count = _current_process._counter.next()                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        self._identity = _current_process._identity + (count,)
```

where `_current_process` is defined later as:

```
class _MainProcess(Process):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

    def __init__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        self._identity = ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        self._daemonic = False                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        self._name = 'MainProcess'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        self._parent_pid = None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        self._popen = None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        self._counter = itertools.count(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        self._children = set()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        self._authkey = AuthenticationString(os.urandom(32))                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        self._tempdir = None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

_current_process = _MainProcess()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
del _MainProcess
```

The thing I don't understand is that `_current_process` is the only instance of the `_MainProcess` class, which is a subclass of `Process`, within which is used `_current_process`. This seems cyclic to me.

1. I doubt this will be able to compile in C++ or JAVA; how does Python deal with this?
2. Moreover, this seems to be an unusual pattern to me; what is the use of it?

The code above is simplified in the following example, which runs fine and prints 42.

```
"""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
parent class definition use a instance of subclass???                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
"""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


class A(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    def print_num(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        print b.num                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


class B(A):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    def __init__(self, num):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        self.num = num                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

b = B(42)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
a = A()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
a.print_num()
```

Comment: the fact that there's only once instance of any member of the class family is incidental. it's no more strange than being able to refer to `self` in an instance method

Comment: Just by looking at your simplified example, why do you think it is strange? objects from the class A can access b which is a in instance of class B.

Comment: @igon,  because I think it is something that cannot be compiled in language like C++, why python allows this, what it differs from C++ that make it able to do this ?

Comment: What it allows python to work exactly like this is the fact that it is a dynamic language. That does not imply that you can not do something similar in C++; it just means that you need to write a few forward declaration to make your compiler happy. See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++ you could get similar results using forward declarations. In Java it's not impossible but you would probably need reflection to get it to work.

The thing here is that the methods are called from the object so the variables exist. Whether it's the child class or parent class that defines it is irrelevant. Everything is done on runtime, so before that time there is no need for `num` to exist.

Using your example:

```
a = A()
a.print_num()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    a.print_num()
  File "test.py", line 9, in print_num
    print b.num
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

Or an even stranger (from a C++/Java point of view) version:

```
class A(object):

    def print_num(self):
        print self.num


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

b = B(42)
b.print_num()
```

Comment: Nice example! It clearly shows something that Python can do since it is a dynamic language.

Answer (score 0):

The `_current_process` variable is always set to the `Process` object for the currently running process. It's global, but its value is actually set in a couple of places. One is the one you initially pointed out, which happens at the top-level of the module:

```
_current_process = _MainProcess()
del _MainProcess
```

This means that when you import the `process` module, directly or indirectly, `_current_process` gets automatically set to the special-case `MainProcess` instance, which represents the top-level process in a script that uses `multiprocessing`.

However, it is also set inside of `Process._bootstrap`, which is called inside a new process immediately after it is forked or spawned:

```
def _bootstrap(self):
    from . import util
    global _current_process

    try:
        ...
        _current_process = self
        ...
```

So, a newly created `Process` has `_current_process` set to itself, rather than the `MainProcess` instance.

Now, when you call `p = Process(...)` in any given process, the properties of that newly created `Process` instance should be based on attributes of the *current process' context*, whatever that may be. Hence this:

```
class Process(object):
    ...   
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        assert group is None, 'group argument must be None for now'
        count = _current_process._counter.next()
        self._identity = _current_process._identity + (count,)
        self._authkey = _current_process._authkey
        self._daemonic = _current_process._daemonic
        self._tempdir = _current_process._tempdir
```

That's why if you have parent, child, and grand-child `Process` instances their names are:

Parent: `<_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>`

Child: `<Process(Process-1, started)>`

Grandchild: `<Process(Process-1:1, started)>`

The grandchild's name is based on the name of child, not the name of the parent.

This kind of pattern is allowed in Python because it uses late binding; variable names and methods aren't bound to objects until runtime. So, the line `self._authkey = _current_process._authkey` is only evaluated when `Process.__init__` is actually called, which will always be after `process.py` is imported, which means `_current_process` will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++ version of your simplified code.
You need a forward declaration of the two classes.

```
class A {
public:
    void print_other_class_member();

};

class B:A {
public:
    int num;
    B();

};
```

Then you declare an instance of class B and use it in the definition of a method of class A.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "forward.h"

class B;

B b;

B::B(){
    num = 42;
}

void A::print_other_class_member(){
    printf("%d\n",b.num);
}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.print_other_class_member();
}
```

This works just fine in C++. The only difference with Python is that you need a forward declaration.